# Scaling a point cloud of object and centering it over original object ensuring they do not intersect

Tags: python, geometry, scale, transformation, point-clouds

I have a rabbit point cloud - can be any object though.

I want to get the larger rabbit directly over the smaller one. Think of a matryoshka dol with different layers. The problem is getting the outer layer to fit perfect around the inner layer . The main body might not overlap but the ears do.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
#IMPORT THE OBJECT POINT CLOUD
c= np.genfromtxt(str('rabbitsmall') + '.txt',autostrip=True)

#Determine the x centre of the original object
xmax = np.amax(c[:,0])
xmin = np.amin(c[:,0])
tx = xmin+(xmax-xmin)/4

#Determine the y centre of the original object
ymax = np.amax(c[:,1])
ymin = np.amin(c[:,1])
ty =ymin+(ymax-ymin)/4

#Determine the z centre of the original object
zmax = np.amax(c[:,2])
zmin = np.amin(c[:,2])
tz = zmin+(zmax-zmin)/2


#CREATE A LARGER VERSION OF THE OBJECT
C = np.zeros((len(c),3))

for i in range(0,len(c)):
               C[i][0]= 1.2*c[i][0]
               C[i][1]= 1.2*c[i][1] 
               C[i][2]= 1.2*c[i][2]

#Determine the x centre of the larger object
Xmax = np.amax(C[:,0])
Xmin = np.amin(C[:,0])
TX = Xmin+(Xmax-Xmin)/4

#Determine the y centre of the larger object
Ymax = np.amax(C[:,1])
Ymin = np.amin(C[:,1])
TY =Ymin+(Ymax-Ymin)/4

#Determine the z centre of the larger object
Zmax = np.amax(C[:,2])
Zmin = np.amin(C[:,2])
TZ = Zmin+(Zmax-Zmin)/2

#TRANSLATE THE LARGER OBJECT TO BE OVER THE SMALLER OBJECT. IE THE CENTRES ARE AT THE SAME PLACE
for i in range(0,len(c)):
               C[i][0]= C[i][0]-(TX-tx)
               C[i][1]= C[i][1]-(TY-ty)
               C[i][2]= C[i][2]-(TZ-tz)


np.savetxt('rabbitlarger.txt',C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to scale it, you want to offset or shell it.

Unfortunately, shelling or offsetting is a little bit trickier than a simple scale.

If I were to try to do it properly, I would first create a Delaunay triangulation of the point cloud, compute the normal for each point using the triangulation (average of adjacent face normals) and then offset each point a certain distance along its normal.

This would probably be good enough for your needs.  If you want something more robust (for example, that can handle when shells cause small holes to completely close up) then I'd suggest something like a distance field that generates a mesh using marching cubes at a certain offset distance.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply , I was actually using this shelling as a way to force my my normals to point outside . I have generated normals for my rabbit and they point outwards almost everywhere except underneath the rabbit and under the chin , i was hoping on getting the normals to point in the direction of the same point on the offset rabbit . Any ideas how I can ensure all my normals point outward, using python with scipy numpy sklearn etc? I've run out if ideas now

Comment: If I were you I'd try http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html